# How Thunar know that my localized "Pobrane" is "Download" directory

Tags: xfce, gtk, thunar, translation

I have Xubuntu instaled (with XFce) and I have custom icon for "Pobrane" (and. Download) and that folder have always is my destination for download (in web browser for instance).

How Ubuntu/Xubuntu know that localized name is Download directory? Where that information is saved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This information is stored in the file `$HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs`. You can edit this file if you want to change some of the folder names.

See the [user-dirs.dirs manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/en/man5/user-dirs.dirs.5.html) for some more information.